# Webhooks for Stack Overflow teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I can enable Slack integration, but our organisation uses a different chat system. There is a [REST API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) which would work, but ensuring that we don't send duplicate messages to our chat is a bit tricky (need a persistent storage to see what the last message posted to chat was), and the oAuth stuff makes it hard/annoying to use outside of web browsers (e.g. on bots running on servers).

It would be wonderful if I could enter a custom HTTP URL to post events to.

Comment: I had assumed that's exactly what the API was. Disappointed it's not. That said, I have 2 questions: 1. Are you sending individual *user related* events to the chat (like specific replies) or just some kind of general "these public events happened" (like a question was posted)? 2. If the former, did you consider the "unread" endpoint? Why didn't it work for you if you did? (Does it not mark things as read once you fetch them?)

Comment: @jpmc26 Thus far, I haven't been able to do anything since I can't get the oAuth nonsense to work well in a non-browser environment :-/

Comment: You could generate the auth token manually in the browser env and set it to expire in like a month or something. That would at least let you test drive the rest of the API and find out if it does what you need, without spending inordinate amounts of time on just the auth piece. If it works, then you'll know doing the auth piece is worth spending the time on. Porting the [example script](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) might also be easier than trying to fight all the details yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion, it's a nice idea and something we are considering on Teams. It's not on our roadmap right now, but it might be something we work on in Q4. I'll keep you updated on here if we do make concrete plans to build it.

Our [Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) product will be supporting webhooks in Q4 this year if this is of any help to you?

Comment: Right now there is native support for Microsoft Teams and Slack notifications, e.g. internal web hooks to these services at the Free level. If web-hooks are important, a work-around could be the creation of a dedicated user that subscribes to every question and omment, and the email is received by SendGrid, SocketLabs, or Mailgun (Inbound Email Parsing) which then calls an HTTP web hook. It's not clean, but it works to get notified that "something" happened. This work around for any modern application shouldn't be needed today.